# Sorting list that includes dates as strings

Tags: python, list, sorting, datetime

I have a following list

```
data = ['Sep 14, 2020', 'Sep 10, 2020', 'Sep 6, 2020', 'Aug 28, 2020', 
    'Aug 25, 2020', 'Aug 31, 2020', 'Aug 30, 2020', 'Aug 17, 2020', 
     'Nov 12, 2020', 'Dec 3, 2020', 'Dec 17, 2020', 'Dec 28, 2020', 'Dec 31, 2020']
```

I've tried looping and matching if date in element set that element behind another one but I cannot get it working

I want to sort list from first month Jan to last month Dec but I don't even know where to start

Comment: Is it possible to do it with sorted function within Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements in `data` are strings, therefore if you run `sort` on the list, it will be sorted alphabetically.

You can tell the `sort` function to sort them considering they are dates. To do this, you need to convert them using `datetime.strptime` like this `datetime.strptime(element, '%b %d, %Y')` (read more about about `strptime` [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime))

So your sort function becomes:

```
data = ['Sep 14, 2020', 'Sep 10, 2020', 'Sep 6, 2020', 'Aug 28, 2020', 'Aug 25, 2020', 'Aug 31, 2020', 'Aug 30, 2020', 'Aug 17, 2020', 'Nov 12, 2020', 'Dec 3, 2020', 'Dec 17, 2020', 'Dec 28, 2020', 'Dec 31, 2020']

data.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d, %Y'))
print(data)
```

Outputs:

```
['Aug 17, 2020', 'Aug 25, 2020', 'Aug 28, 2020', 'Aug 30, 2020', 'Aug 31, 2020', 'Sep 6, 2020', 'Sep 10, 2020', 'Sep 14, 2020', 'Nov 12, 2020', 'Dec 3, 2020', 'Dec 17, 2020', 'Dec 28, 2020', 'Dec 31, 2020']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your strings into datetime objects and then sort them:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = ['Sep 14, 2020', 'Sep 10, 2020', 'Sep 6, 2020', 'Aug 28, 2020', 'Aug 25, 2020', 'Aug 31, 2020', 'Aug 30, 2020', 'Aug 17, 2020', 'Nov 12, 2020', 'Dec 3, 2020', 'Dec 17, 2020', 'Dec 28, 2020', 'Dec 31, 2020']

dates = list(map(lambda time_str: datetime.strptime(time_str, "%b %d, %Y"), data))
dates.sort()

print(dates)

# or if you want them as strings
print(list(map(lambda x: x.strftime("%b %d, %Y"), dates)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**What you had:**

```
data = ['Sep 14, 2020', 'Sep 10, 2020', 'Sep 6, 2020', 'Aug 28, 2020', 'Aug 25, 2020',
        'Aug 31, 2020', 'Aug 30, 2020', 'Aug 17, 2020', 'Nov 12, 2020', 'Dec 3, 2020',
        'Dec 17, 2020', 'Dec 28, 2020', 'Dec 31, 2020']
```

**What you need to add:**

```
import datetime

r = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%b %d, %Y')

data.sort(key=r)
```

**Result:**

```
['Aug 17, 2020',
 'Aug 25, 2020',
 'Aug 28, 2020',
 'Aug 30, 2020',
 'Aug 31, 2020',
 'Sep 6, 2020',
 'Sep 10, 2020',
 'Sep 14, 2020',
 'Nov 12, 2020',
 'Dec 3, 2020',
 'Dec 17, 2020',
 'Dec 28, 2020',
 'Dec 31, 2020']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `key` argument to the `sort` method which will tell Python how to sort the items.  For example, suppose I wanted to sort a list of strings based on the alphabetical order of their **last** letters.

```
words = ['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie']
words.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])
print(words)
```

Output:

```
['alfa', 'charlie', 'bravo']
```

So, you would need to write a function to pass as the `key` to tell when one date string is "less than" another.  This would work:

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

data=sort(key=lambda x: months.index(x.split()[0])*100 + int(x.split()[1]))
```

Comment: God bless you thank you <3 you guys are actual geniuses

Comment: Thanks!  However, after seeing the other answers, I suggest you go with them instead of mine.  Much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer much appreciated